# Masstransit temporary queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm developing client application which use masstransit and rabbitmq. On application start I'm creating new queue with unique name for communication with server applications via masstransit(request/response model). On application closing I should delete this queue, but if client application crushes queue will present on rabbitmq.

Is it possible to create temporary queue via masstransit which rabbitmq will automatically delete when client disconnects from queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a temporary queue by using the `?temporary=true` query string parameter.

With RabbitMQ, you can also dynamically create the queue name by using `*` as the queue name. Such as:

```
x.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/vhost/*?temporary=true");
```

This would create a temporary queue with a randomly generated name that is deleted when the connection is closed.

Comment: Is it possible to add a prefix? something like "rabbitmq://localhost/vhost/app-*?temporary=true"

Comment: That would be a nice addition, I'll put an issue in GitHub to track it.

Comment: @chris-patterson Does this still work under MT v3 or is there a different mechanism?

Comment: With MT3, use the ReceiveEndpoint overload without a queue name to generate a temporary queue. Consumers will be bound to the queue and exchange as expected. The management endpoint uses this approach as well.